# How to get the class attribute of a <span> inside a <li> by id of the <li> element

Tags: jquery, razor

In my _Layout.cshtml I have a `<span>` inside a `<li>` such as:

```
<li id="li-id">
    <span class="my-btn-click">Button</span>
</li>
```

where only the id of the `<li>` element is known and I want to get the class attribute of the `<span>` element (whose id and class is not known).

I tried

`var classAttr = $("#li-id").closest("span").attr("class")`

but that gives 'undefined'.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.closest()` only works upwards. You have to use `$('#li-id').find('span').attr('class')` (if you use jquery, your question only states javascript tough.)

Comment: @cloned Is `.find` somehow favorited instead of a simple child selector in jQuery?

Comment: And when you tried `closest`and didn't work. Did you search what closest does ? It clearly says  " For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree. " . Key : traversing up through its ancestors. Second, you don't need an extra jquery/javascript method to find it. You can just change the selector ( in this specific case ). Third, what you have posted is jquery not plain javascript. Please change your tags accordingly

Comment: depends on what you want to do and what you currently have available. You can store the wrapper in a variable and target multiple elements via `find()` . like ` var divs = $el.find('div'); var spans = $el.find('span')` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of closest() is wrong.

```js
console.log($("#li-id").find("span").attr("class"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="li-id">
    <span class="my-btn-click">Button</span>
</li>
```

Comment: I have several other spans on the page and when I use find('span') I get a class list not related to the span that I am targetting at. For testing I added an Id to the span and used find('#mySpan') then the class attribute is returned correctly. Any suggestion how to get the class attribute of just the span that is inside the li with the known id?

Comment: The code above will find only spans in `#li-id`. If you have multiple span in that `#li-id`, you have to be more specific with selector. For example, you can find direct child spans with `find("> span")`.

Comment: Using $("#li-id").find("span").eq(1).attr("class"); did work to get the class attribute of the span that I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
var classAttr = $("#li-id > span").attr("class");
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you can get that class using query selector:

```
var classAttr = document.querySelector('li#li-id span').attributes.class.value
```